# How to implement a smooth transition between two different camera view in opengl

Tags: opengl, view, transition

gluLookAt is defined as follows

```
void gluLookAt(GLdouble eyeX, GLdouble eyeY, GLdouble eyeZ,
               GLdouble centerX, GLdouble centerY, GLdouble centerZ,
               GLdouble upX, GLdouble upY, GLdouble upZ
              );
```

I have two different cameras parameters corresponding to gluLookAt,I am confused about how to implement a smooth transition between views of these two camera parameters.

I hope that somebody can give me some cue or some code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using [Spherical Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) (slerp) on the rotations produced by `gluLookAt (...)`. The GLM math library (C++) provides everything you need for this, including an implementation of `LookAt`.

#### Very roughly, this is what a GLM-based implementation might look like:

```
// Create quaternions from the rotation matrices produced by glm::lookAt
glm::quat quat_start (glm::lookAt (eye_start, center_start, up_start));
glm::quat quat_end   (glm::lookAt (eye_end,   center_end,   up_end));

// Interpolate half way from original view to the new.
float interp_factor = 0.5; // 0.0 == original, 1.0 == new

// First interpolate the rotation
glm::quat  quat_interp = glm::slerp (quat_start, quat_end, interp_factor);

// Then interpolate the translation
glm::vec3  pos_interp  = glm::mix   (eye_start,  eye_end,  interp_factor);

glm::mat4  view_matrix = glm::mat4_cast (quat_interp); // Setup rotation
view_matrix [3]        = glm::vec4 (pos_interp, 1.0);  // Introduce translation
```